# Javascript LightBox 2 : strange size ratio of pictures

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I am using the last version of [LightBox 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) (sample available)

CSS and javascript are loaded with :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/lightbox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lightbox-2.6.min.js"></script>
```

LightBox works but size of clicked pictures have a strange ratio....

http://kriyas-yoga.com/pages/accommodation

Real sizes of pictures are :

small pictures 150 X 150
large pictures 400 X 400

Thank you for reading.

PS: Site is in progress...

Comment: I know size is defined in the "lb-outerContainer", but this "div" is generated by the LightBox plugin....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is with your css. Please remove the style

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

on your stylesheet named "style.css" at line number 43.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Actually this css is a part of the front-end framework, so I cannot delete it... :-(

Comment: Fixed with   [ max-width: none !important; ]  Thank you